# Problem when summing the result of NewBoolVars

Tags: or-tools

I have a set of buyer and seller NewBoolVars for each instance of time. At the ending of scheduling the buyers and sellers. I would like to only include the buyers and sellers that have had their chargeRequest attribute fulfilled to be included in the final calculation. I sum up a row of a respective 2D array of boolVars, **(buy)** and **(sell)**. Should I switch to intVars since this gives errors?[Code for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNt9j.png)

I get an error that the NewBoolVars cannot be summed: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC5yR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

An IntVar or a BoolVar is not a integer value. It is an opaque whose value can be queried from the solver after solver when the solve has been successful.

`sum(bool_vars) == 3` makes no sense. `sum(bool_vars)` is an opaque object interpreted by the solver as a linear expression.

This questions has been ask many times. You should look at this [doc page](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling).

Comment: So, I should make an intermediary BoolVar which uses the "OnlyEnforceIf" field in order to force this condition?

Comment: Exactly. And most likely its negation with the literal.Not().